# cond in Clojure with thousands of clauses

Tags: clojure

Running the following code in Clojure gives a StackOverflow Error:

```
(cond 
 (= 1 2) 1
 (= 2 3) 2
 (= 3 4) 3

 ...

 (= 1022 1023) 1022
 (= 1023 1024) 1023
 :else 1024)
```

I would like to create a function/macro that can handle a huge number of clauses without creating a stack that overflows.

Please advise as to how I might attempt this.

Comment: can you shed some light on the issue you're trying to solve with a `cond` that big? It may help us answer your question.

Comment: Clojure does not have tail call optimization, but you can [use recur](http://clojure.org/functional_programming#Functional%20Programming--Recursive%20Looping) to avoid the stack problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Kyle: I came across this problem when I was translating a huge SQL case statement into clojure. In reality, the sql statement would have been better coded as a join. So, to be honest I mainly asked because think this is an interesting coding problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the full stack trace, you'll see that `cond` emits a deeply-nested `if` structure; the exception then occurs when the compiler tries to parse this structure. The problem might have more to do with simply compiling deeply nested Clojure code than the specific use of `cond`.

I was able to come up with the following macro that takes a list of clauses, wraps them in thunks to provide the deferred evaluation that you get with `if`, and then uses `some` to find the first logical true test expression. Its performance probably isn't as good due to the creation of so many anonymous functions, but it gets around the stack overflow exception.

```
(defmacro cond' [& clauses]
  `(:result
    (some (fn [[pred-thunk# val-thunk#]]
            (if (pred-thunk#) {:result (val-thunk#)}))
          (partition 2 (list ~@(map (fn [c] `(fn [] ~c)) clauses))))))
```

Note the wrapping and unwrapping of the returned value in a map, to ensure that `some` correctly handles a value clause that evaluates to nil.

Answer (score 5):

A `cond` with 513 clauses in unlikely to be used in practice.

Here is a functional implementation of your example.

```
(or (some identity (map #(if (= %1 %2) %1)
                     (range 1 1024)
                     (range 2 1025)))
    1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **requirement** is like this:

1. Given a list of condition and result mappings, e.g.

   `[ [cond1 r1] [cond2 r2] ...]`, where

   cond1: `(= 1 1)`,

   r1: `1`
2. Find the result - `rn` - where `condn` evaluates to true

**Solution** using `some` is perfect here in solving the problem, but I think we can **avoid using macro**.

```
(defn match [[condition result]]
  (when condition result))

(some match [[(= 1 2) 100] [(= 2 3) 200] [(= 3 3) 300]])   ;; => 300
```